How to display charts on crystal report from right to left?
I work on crystal report I face issue I can't display charts on crystal report from right to left .
so are there are any property or workaround  on chart Make charts start from right to left
I try to put chart on text object and make format object - paragraph- right to left but not working


Are you sure this issue is related to Highcharts? Either way, in Highcharts, you can reverse the direction of a chart by setting the reversed and opposite properties of both the xAxis and yAxis to true.

it is related to crystal report charts
